# Is there any better way to find the closest points' distance?

Tags: algorithms

The problem is:

> Suppose you're given $n$ points in the coordinate plane, and for convenience assume that no two of their $x$ or $y$ coordinates are the same. Design an algorithm that finds the shortest possible distance between a pair of these points. What is the time complexity of your algorithm?

Ofcourse there is a easy way to find the shortest distance in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$. But, is there any better algorithm? I am out of idea.

*Note*: I am a Math major and not familiar with CS way to solve problems very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the well-known [closest pair of points problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem), and you can solve it for $n$ points in $O(n \log n)$ time by divide and conquer.

A pretty cool randomized algorithm [due to Rabin](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/rabin-flips-a-coin/) is also available.